# How make do loop to check , sum cell value and stop in right place

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I would like to stop loop after sum values ​​in the column be over 40    R"D1:D10" {10,12,12,32,321,12,....} and write how many numbers/cells    had to add. I need use do loop

```
Sub LOOOP ()
Dim sum As Integer
Dim i As Integer

sum = 0
Do
For i = 1 To 10
sum = sum + Cells(i, 4).Value
Next i
Loop While sum < 40

End Sub
```

Comment: Can we go through a cell several times while the sum is less than 40?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This program should solve your problem:

```
Sub LOOOP()
Dim sum As Integer
Dim sumTmp As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim countIteration As Integer
sum = 0
countIteration = 0
For i = 1 To 11
    countIteration = countIteration + 1
    sum = sum + Cells(i, 4).Value
    If (sum > 40) Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Next i
If (sum > 40) Then
   Cells(1, 5).Value = "Sum: " + Str(sum)
   Cells(1, 6).Value = "Iterations: " + Str(countIteration)
Else
    sum = 20
    Cells(1, 5).Value = "Sum: " + Str(sum)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But what if in this 10 cells value won't be big enough to be over 40?

Comment: It will go through another time the 10 cells. This is what you want no?

Comment: or you want the 10 cells to be scanned only once?

Comment: My bad, I was not precise, I wanted to check values after first time and then  if be over 40  show me  "sum" and "countIteration"  else  assigns a "sum" value 10,20,30 or something

Comment: I tried this, he didn't  assign value to sum in elseif
Code:   
 Do
   
        For i = 1 To 11
         
            sumTmp = sum + Cells(i, 4).Value
            If (i < 11 And sumTmp < 60) Then
                 sum = sumTmp
                 countIteration = countIteration + 1
           ElseIf (i < 11 And sumTmp < 20) Then
                 sum = 10
                
           Else
           Exit Do
         
                 End If
        Next i
        
    Loop While True

Comment: Firstly your condition i < 11 is not necessary because she is still true. And to answer your question, he didn't assign value to sum in elseif because the first if (sumTmp < 60) is also true when sumTmp is less than 20.  So reverse the order of your two if confditions. Like this:          If (sumTmp < 20) Then
           sum = 10
 ElseIf (sumTmp < 60) Then
           sum = sumTmp
           countIteration = countIteration + 1 Else
                Exit Do
            End If

Comment: @Homar i don't really understand your goal, if you explain me more i can help you better.

Comment: Your idea , didn't work loop didn't stop  for sum <20 ,I have ten number in column I need to check (only once )when sum of these numbers will  be over 40 and write how many  cells had to check to know it  but if sum in 10 cells will be less  40 i want to assign sum value to 10   "Cells(1, 5).Value = "Sum: " + Str(sum) =10"

Comment: @Homar I updated my solution, it should be good.